# How might one measure the time it takes a program to run in a standardized way that does not take into account processor speed?

Tags: python

I am building a chess program and would like to compare the efficiencies of different versions. I want my data to be reproducible on any machine, so I don't think timing in seconds will work well. Is there any way to track how many lines are executed without having lines_executed++ after every line?

Comment: Why not big O notation? Because it is theoretical speed

Comment: Wouldn't the amount of time depend on the processor speed? What you need is a way to measure performance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency

Comment: As others the have said above me, the way to do what you're asking is by analizing your algorithms efficienty. That can prove a little tricky sometimes though, specially if you've never done it before. Check out this article if you've never used big O notation https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/. Also take into account that the amount of lines of code executed is far from being a way to measure performance.

Comment: Also a good thing to note is that just because someone used more lines of code to complete a task doesn't mean it has worse performance, and more lines could mean better readability and adaptation of the code instead of using a one liner